# preg_match and PHP concatenating

Tags: php, string-concatenation

Sorry to bother you but I'm having some trouble with my preg_match parameters. This isn't so much a preg_match question as it is a concatenating question. If I have a variable like $a['state'] and I'm trying to match it to an array of possible states, how do I handle the slashes? This is what I have now but it doesn't work:

```
if (preg_match("/'" . $a['mystate'] . "'/",$row['state'])){
    echo 'yes, a match';    
}else{
    echo 'got nothing';
    exit;
}
```

Comment: please post an example of what $a['mystate'] outputs and what $row['state'] outputs

Comment: are you getting an error? does `$a['mystate']` have any regex characters like `[]()^$/\ ` ...etc? You should probably use something like http://www.php.net/preg_quote on `$a['mystate']` to escape the regex characters.

Comment: $row['state'] is the array -- it looks like this: 
array(PA, CA, RI, VA, MD)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing an in_array call instead:

```
echo (in_array($a['mystate'], $row['state'])) ? 'Match found!' : ' No match';
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me that you don't need `preg_match` but `strpos` instead:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

```
if ( strpos($a['mystate'],$row['state']) !== FALSE ){
   // match
}else{
   // no match
}
```

**OR**, event better solution would be to use `in_array`...

**EDIT:**

I saw your comment and `in_array' is definetely the function you're looking for...

http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php